# How can I set an extra session cookie on cas server, after login

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I need to set an extra domain session cookie (unrelated to security) after the user has logged in on cas. All cas clients share the same domain, so each one of them will be able to see the cookie.

How can I set an extra cookie in cas `5.2.x`?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to extend the CAS configuration to write a special webflow component. In that component, you get access to the request/response objects and can inject the cookie.

References:

- https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Management-Extensions.html
- https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Webflow-Customization-Extensions.html